# How to call a method every time a variable is called

Tags: java, selenium, dynamic

So I have a variable that uses a method. Something like this:

```
By locator = By.id("something-"+getDynamicId());
```

Usually the id changes numbers like this: something-1 to something-2 (not those exact numbers, always different). I have a way of getting the number it changes to by calling the getDynamicId() method. The problem is, when I start my test the id is set at the start and whenever I click on a specific button, the id changes but my variable does not. Is it possible for the *locator* variable to call getDynamicId() everytime *locator* is called? Maybe everytime I click on the specific button the locator reloads?

I have looked up ClassLoaders but I do not know how to use it nor do I know if it can even do what I want.

Comment: Use **Observer** Pattern

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing that, i've gotten around dynamic ID's by using CSS.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("element[id^='something']"));
```

This means "find an `<element>` tag, that has an `id` attribute that `starts with` "something"

If there are multiple elements that match this, then you need to increase your specificity.  You can do this by selecting some parent.

```
div.some-div [id^='something']

            ^  the space here meaning "a descendent of.."
```

[this page](http://ddavison.io/css/2014/02/18/effective-css-selectors.html) may help with formulating CSS selectors like this for Selenium.

Comment: I can't do that because this isn't the only locator, this is just an example. There are hundreds that start with something and all of them shift by some random number each time something is clicked.

Comment: then use parent/child selectors as well.  You can combine selectors.  `div.some-parent element[id^='something']`

Answer (score 0):

Also, in addition to what @sircapsalot has done, you can use xpath for working with dynamic ids as below (As you said in comment, there are multiple element having ids that contains "something"):

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//tag[contains(@id,'something-')]"));
//Say you want to click on 4th element now then use the below code(assuming the list has more than or equal to 4 elements in it)
elements.get(3).click();
```

Here, it will locate all the elements with tag as **"tag"** and has **"id"** that contains the text **"something-"** and then click on the 4th element in the list.

---

But, if you want to retrieve the dynamic ID and use it for clicking on the specific element, you can create a new method like this :

```
public static void clickOnDynamicElementById(String partial_locator_id){

    //Code for getting dynamic id and then storing the retrieved dynamic ID in a string, say "dynaID";

    String locator_id_to_click = partial_locator_id + dynaID;

    driver.findElement(By.id("locator_id_to_click")).click();

}
```

Then, you can call this method directly in your main method as below:

```
  clickOnDynamicElement("something-"); //because main method is also static, it can call the method directly.
```

Comment: there is more than one element with something

Comment: Check the first code above. I have modified that to click on the 3rd element that has id with "something-" in it. Does this help ?

Comment: And, probably the second code will also help too because you are generating the dynamic ID in that method, then concatenating with "something-" text, and then using that as the locator click on the element.

Comment: List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//tag[contains(@id,'something-')]")); this will only work at the very beginning. When I click on something and all the ids change, all of these elements may now be invalid.

Comment: Then please try the second idea of creating a new method `clickOnDynamicElementById`. This way you will be generating the dynamic ID each time and then concatenating with "something-" to make the relevant ID and click on it later.